# php mysql pdo auction bidding

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am developing an auction system with a limit or max bid scenario using php mySQL(MyISAM) and PDO, using two tables

**auction**

```
 Id   | title | seller  |  currentbid   |  limit(max bid)   |  dated | bidder
```

**bids**

```
 Id  | auctionid | bid  | bidder | dated
```

After user placed a bid the following happens (I am using PDO prepared statements)

```
 $record = fetch (‘Select * from auction where id = :id’, array(‘id’ => $id))
 $increment = 1;
 $postedBid = $_REQUEST[‘postedBid’];
 $currentBid = $record[‘currentbid’];
 $limitBid = $record[‘limit’];

 If($postedBid < $currentBid + $increment){
    Return;(without processing bid!)
 }else{
    If($limitBid !> $postedBid){
       Insert into bids (auctionid, bid, bidder, dated(timestamp)) values ($auctioned, $postedBid, ……);

       Update auction set currentbid = $postedBid, limit = $postedBid ….

       }else{

       Insert into bids (auctionid, bid, bidder, dated(timestamp)) values ($auctioned, $postedBid, ……);

       Insert into bids (auctionid, bid, bidder, dated(timestamp)) values ($auctioned, $postedBid + $increment, ……);

       Update auction set currentbid = $postedBid + increment, limit = $limitBid ….
      }
  }
```

i want to know two things

1- if this approach is ok and how can I improve this

2- How can I avoid concurrent bids. I don’t know how to apply locks using PDO. Appreciate any example queries using locks or any other approach to deal with this problem

Thanks

(Apologies for using mixed type of code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do this in a store procedure in MySQL that simply returns a success/failure message.

You would need to change your code to be something like this:

```
If($postedBid < $currentBid + $increment){
   Return;(without processing bid!)
} else {
   $stmt = $db->prepare("CALL update_bid(?,?, ...)");
   $stmt->execute(array($parameter1, $parameter2, ...));
}
```

Keep your checking in the code as well to help prevent unnecessary db calls, the stored proc will just help ensure no concurrency problems.

Comment: hmmm great actually i am a newbie to mysql didn't know it has procedure facility i will definitely look into it. Thanks

Comment: "basic support" for stored procedures was present in 5.0.0